# PHP - Update file sucessfully but update text failed

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a simple update form for text and file. This is my code

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE id= '$id'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{   

?>

<html><head><title>test</title></head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    ID: <?php echo $id; ?><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

    Contract Title
    <input type="text" name="contract_title" value="<?php echo $row['contract_title']; ?>" /><br>

    Upload File:
    <?php echo $row['filename'] ?>
    <input type="file" name="upload"/><br>  
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}

if(isset($_POST['edit'])  )
{

if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){

$contract_title = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['contract_title']);

$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filedata= $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

$query = "UPDATE `contracts` set `filename` = '$filename',`filedata` = '$filedata', `filetype` = '$filetype',`filesize` = '$filesize' WHERE `id` = '$id' " ;

if ($con->query($query) == TRUE) {
echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error:<br>" . $con->error;
}

} else {

$contract_title = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['contract_title']);

$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

$query = "UPDATE `contracts` set `filename` = '$filename', `filetype` = '$filetype',`filesize` = '$filesize' WHERE `id` = '$id' " ;

if ($con->query($query) == TRUE) {
echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error:<br>" . $con->error;
}

}
$con->close(); 
}   

?>
```

After I clicked submit button, it successfully updated the file upload except the text. I don't want to change from post to get method because that will do the same problem to the upload file process. How do I fix this?

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection, keep this in mind;

Comment: if you echoed the `$filedata` can you see anything printed ?

Comment: @hassan it said undefined variable on line 7

Comment: print your variable after declaring it , `$filedata= $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])); echo $filedata;`

Comment: Undefined index: upload on line 7 and file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty on line 7

Comment: this happens after submit the form ?

Comment: @hassan no but before submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this time after looking for mistakes at the code for hours, this is a simple mistake that I missed!

```
$query = "UPDATE `contracts` set `contract_title` = '$contract_title', `filename` = '$filename',`filedata` = '$filedata', `filetype` = '$filetype',`filesize` = '$filesize' WHERE `id` = '$id' " ;
```

I didn't type the contract_title in the query! my god

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are not getting the $filename correctly. Try debugging and print $_FILES['upload']['name'], see what you get (you can json_encode and see the results you are trying to access). Rest of the code seems to be okay

Comment: $filename is already correct and when I tried print $_FILES['upload']['name'], it displays undefined index upload.